# Defining structs in C

Tags: c, struct

so I have this code:

```
 typedef struct node link;
 struct node {int v; link *next;};
 struct graph{int V; int E; link **adj;};
```

In the first line I get the error "Redefinition of link as different kind of symbol".

In the second line and third I get "Unkown type name "link"".

Any ideas?

EDIT: I changed the name link to something else and it works, although I don't have anything else named link in my project.

Comment: are you sure that's all the code you've got?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Yes, that's all the code I have and I'm using the correct compiler, the problem is, as stated by Joachim Pileborg, there's a system function called link in POSIX platforms.

Comment: @RuiLoureiro Well, then, there you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a POSIX platform (like Linux or OSX) there's a system function called [`link`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html).

Structure names, like your `struct node`, lives in a separate name-space (which is why you could do e.g. `typedef struct node node;`), but type-aliases lives in the same name-space as everything else which means that if you have a function `link` you can't have a type-alias with the same name.

Comment: Since I'm using Xcode, that must be the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Joachim has already given the answer. The real hint is in the compiler warning: **Redefinition** of link as a **different** kind of symbol. You are defining a new type, but link is already defined as something else. This definition fails.
Therefore, when using the type in line 2 and 3, you get the unknown type name error.